# remove characters from variable

Tags: php

```
$dir = '/web99/web/direcotry/filename';
```

I need to drop '/web99/web/' from the directory on the fly.

I tried:

```
$trimmed = ltrim($dir, "/web99/web/");
```

however if a directory started with a w,e,b,9 the first letter of the directory was cut off.

How can I drop only what I want and not every character like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$dir = preg_replace('$^/web99/web/$', '', $dir);`

Comment: @sam Use this one if you want to replace `/web99/web/` only at the start of `$dir`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$dir = str_replace('/web99/web/', '', $dir);
```

Comment: @sam Use this one if you want to replace all occurrences of `/web99/web/` in `$dir`.

Comment: @Oswald: I think that in this particular case there's no practical possibility of more than one match. `str_replace` is more easy to understand, so I preferred it given the question's level.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `str_replace` if you know that it will never be anywhere else in the path:

```
$trimmed = str_replace('/web99/web/', '', $dir);
```

If you wanted to be *really* safe, you could use `preg_replace` to get the beginning of the string:

```
$trimmed = preg_replace('~^/web99/web/~', '', $dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use strtr(), so if you need other string replacements, editing will be easy :

```
$trimmed = strtr($dir, array('/web99/web/'=>''));
```